# Category from base.html in all views?

Tags: django

I have category model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

and I want in my base html have list of my category. How to do?

```
  <ul>
        <li class="category">Search Property</li>

        {% for cat in category %}
            <li class="category_link"><a href="/category/{{ cat.slug }}/">{{ cat.name }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}    
    </ul>
```

views.py

```
def category(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('base.html',{'category':category}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^cat/','content.views.category'),
)
```

This work only in **127.0.0.1:8000/cat**

I need this in my all views(my category are displayed in base.html). How to do?

Comment: If you need it in all views, I would use a middleware to "inject" it and add it to your session and then fetch it from there in your `base.html`

Comment: Sounds good, how to add this function to middleware?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware - Here ya go

Comment: middlewares are not the best tool for the job - better to use a custom templatetag here.

Comment: as a side note, hardcoding urls in the templates is bad practice. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse for the right way to build urls in Django.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Django template tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

in app/templatetags/categories.py

```
    from django.template.base import Library

    register = Library()


    @register.inclusion_tag('path/to/template')
    def categories():

        categories = Category.objects.all()
        return {'categories': categories,}
```

In html

```
{% load categories %}
```

and where you want to include tha categories

```
{% categories %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Write a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) which returns a list of Categories. Something as simple as this should work:

```
def all_categories(request):
    return {'ALL_CATEGORIES': Category.objects.all()}
```

and add it to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting.

Note that in doing this, `ALL_CATEGORIES` will be available in every template context which uses a [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext).